# Array-map example in clojure

Tags: clojure, array-map

I am learning clojure and trying to implement a problem. I am storing maps in a vector. Each  map contains an id. For example `[{:id 1 :name "abc"} {:id 2 :name "xyz"}]`. The map also contains some more fields.

I read somewhere that, instead of using a vector to store the maps, I could use an array-map and do away with my id and store it something like `{1 {:name "abc"}, 2 {:name "xyz"}}`.

I tried going through the clojure docs but didn't find a good example to achieve this. Can some please help me out and give me a good example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assoc` to add values to a map. `assoc` takes 3 args. The first arg is the map that you want to add to, 2nd arg is a key, and the third is a value. The function returns the old map with the key-value pair added.

Example:

```
(assoc {} 1 {:name "abc"})
```

returns

```
{1 {:name "abc"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is to lift the `:id` entry of each record-map into an index, while removing it from the map. You end up with a map of `:id`-less records instead of a vector of full records.

The following function lifts the key `fk` out of the collection of maps `ms`:

```
(defn key-by [fk ms]
  (into {} (map (fn [m] [(get m fk) (dissoc m fk)]) ms)))
```

For example,

```
(key-by :id [{:id 1 :name "abc"} {:id 2 :name "xyz"}])
;{1 {:name "abc"}, 2 {:name "xyz"}}
```

Note:

- Every record should have an `:id`.
- Your `:id`s had better be distinct, or you'll lose records.
- Don't depend on `array-map`: it's an implementation detail. A
  modified    version might well be a `hash-map`.

  - If you need your map sorted by key, use a `sorted-map`.
  - If you need to keep your records in insertion order, think again.

Comment: Okay I get what you say trying to say, i ll think if i really need an array-map (or any map for that matter) or just keep it in a vector